# Tomcat in eclipse ignores log4j.properties

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

My WebApplication in eclipse uses `slf4j` for logging. When running my app in tomcat inside eclipse the `log4j.properties` seems to be ignored, as neither a logfile is created nor my loglevel or logging format is used.

Only inside the tomcat console my logs with loglevel WARN and higher are displayed. I placed the file inside WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib as suggested in another thread but without success.
I also set below arguments in the tomcat server

```
-Dlog4j.debug=true 
-Dlog4j.configuration="file:/Prgs/apache-tomcat-9.0.17/conf/log4j.properties"
```

Comment: Tomcat does not use Log4J, this is not a Tomcat problem. Log4J 1 is dead.

Comment: I don't want to log tomcat but the apps it's running...

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar to WEB-INF/lib folder instead of slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar